# Drawing the cross-section contour plot for an ellipsoid (as shown in corel diagram)

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d, matlab-figure

This is the image I got using `slice` command. Can't get for finer mesh grid:

[image: This is the image I got using slice command. Can't get for finer mesh grid]

This image shows the pressure contours around an ellipsoid along X-Y, Y-Z, and X-Z planes separately:

[image: This image shows the pressure contours around an ellipsoid along X-Y, Y-Z, and X-Z planes separately.]

I have used MATLAB to plot these diagrams. I want to show all these planes in a single 3-D plot of an ellipsoid. Can it be done using MATLAB or any other platform?

```
% 3D meshgrid in clast's coordinate
    xgv     = 0;           % grid vector: x'axis,a1
    ygv     = -8:0.1:8;           % grid vector: y'axis,a2
    zgv     = -6:0.1:6;    % grid vector: z'axis,a3
    [X,Y,Z] = meshgrid(xgv,ygv,zgv);



    % Exterior points
    ind   = (X./1).^2 + (Y./a(2)).^2 + (Z./a(3)).^2 > 1;
    x_ex  = X(ind);
    y_ex  = Y(ind);
    z_ex  = Z(ind);
    ep    = cat(1,x_ex',y_ex',z_ex');
    % total points number
    num   = numel(X);
    % exterior points number
    [~,n] = size(ep);


    % Exterior Fields  
    % 
      G = Ex_Gtensor(a,ep); % this is some function to calculate pressure at 
               external points
      Here I use some algorithm to calculate pressure field outside ellipsoid.
    %--------------------------------------------------
    pressure        = zeros(num,1);
    pressure(~ind)  = p1;
    pressure(ind)   = p2;
    % So this pressure variable has all the pressure values for all external points 
    pressure        = reshape(pressure,size(squeeze(Z)));


    contourf(squeeze(Y),squeeze(Z),pressure)
    hold on
    axis equal
    % Similarly I use this code for X-Y and X-Z plane.
```

Kindly let me know if any other information is needed.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you know [`slice`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/slice.html?s_tid=doc_ta)?

Comment: Hi @EBH ! Thanks for your reply ! I tried using the slice and getting some plots. However, I can't get the results for finer mesh grids.It is showing that results of pressure calculation are coming in complex number format for finer mesh grids. Is there any advice you can give? ( I have edited the question and added the slice results.)